# Developing Wordpress site behind a static site

Tags: theme-development, redirect

I am converting a site to wordpress on a new host after a previous server host shut down unexpectedly. The old site was on CMSMadesimple, which I am no longer  supporting.
Wordpress is in the www directory following a one-click install, and I've already done quite a bit of work on it.

In the meantime, I've put up a static html version of the site extracted from backups. This has an index.html page, with all other pages in a subdirectory.
DirectoryIndex is set to index.html index.php

The problem is that during theme development previews are all showing the static version.
I mistakenly reconfigured the wordpress base url to [domain]/index.php, but this is causing most pages to 404 and giving me difficulty logging in.

What is the best way to deal with this situation? The client is being very patient, but then I am married to her :-)

Update: I've managed to fix the base url via phpmyadmin, so login problem is resolved.

Comment: The static version being the html splash? If so, don’t bother around with the index.html static / index.php WordPress dance. Either put WordPress in it’s own directory, like /wordpress/ and change the home URL once ready to launch, or, do some redirects at code level, like a `if (!is_user_logged_in()) { include('../wtv/splash.html'); die; }` at the top of your theme/plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I've now solved this by:
1) copying my index.html to the /old/ directory (and updating navigation in other pages)
2) Installing a "Coming Soon" plugin, ([this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/coming-soon/)) which, to my surprise, let me override the template and paste in the entire content of my index.html page.